# SED Command for printing the lines after matching particular pattern

Tags: shell, awk, sed

A text file will be delivered on fly. with labels like Fruits , Animals , Vehicles.
but the order is not fixed. it changes.

```
Fruits: 
1. apple
2. Mango
3. Banana
4. Pineapple
5. Orange


Animals:
1. Cow
2. Dog
3. fox
```

now with the help of SED script I have to print only the Fruits. then output should be like the below.

```
apple
Mango
Banana
Pineapple
Orange
```

Any Command for to help this.

Answer (score -1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -rn '/:/h;G;s/^[0-9]+\. (.*)\nFruits:.*/\1/p' file
```

Store the header in the hold space and append it to each line. When the line contains `Fruits in the second line of the pattern space, using substitution print the required format.